# how to configure vhost.conf for a subdomain?

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost, httpd.conf, vhosts

I am operating a site created with Laravel. I tried to set up a subdomain and build another Laravel site on same server, and set the directory structure and settings as below, but it is not displayed as intended.

I would like to display `/www/html/site2/index.php` on subdomain.site1.org.
but when i hit subdomain.site1.org, `www/html/index.html` is displayed.
The laravel site is working on `subdomain.site1.org/site2/`.

I would appreciate it if you could teach me what is wrong in ↓

www/
┣ html/
┃  ┣ index.html
┃  ┣ site1/
┃  ┃  ┗ index.php
┃  ┗ site2/
┃      ┗ index.php
┣ site1/
┗ site2/

```
    <VirtualHost *:80><br />
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2<br />
    ServerName subdomain.site1.org<br />
    CustomLog logs/subdomainsite1org-access.log common<br />
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8<br />
    <Directory "/var/www/html/site2/"><br />
    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks<br />
    AllowOverride All<br />
    Order allow,deny<br />
    Allow from all<br />
    Require all granted<br />
    </Directory><br />
    RewriteEngine on<br />
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =subdomain.site1.org/site2　　　/* i added "/site2" to laravel word temporary */<br />
    RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]<br />
    </VirtualHost><br />
```

```
    <VirtualHost *:80><br />

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1<br />
    ServerName site1.org<br />
    CustomLog logs/site1org-access.log common<br />
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8<br />
    <Directory "var/www/html/site1/"><br />
    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks<br />
    AllowOverride All<br />
    Order allow,deny<br />
    Allow from all<br />
    </Directory><br />
    RewriteEngine on<br />
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =site1.org<br />
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]<br />
    </VirtualHost><br />
```

Comment: if you get "www/html/index.html" displayed that means you have on top ANOTHER server declared that is serving that file - is that right?  That is not solving your problem, but at least we should sort out things step-by-step. Apache has a (strange) behavior: if the SeverName is not matching, Apache will just call the first Server in the list. To warn in that case, I declared one "dummy" Server in my vhost in first place with a simple html message to display that the ServerName could not be resolved.